# How do we reinstate our patent US 5,341,526

Tags: patent-lifetime, fees, maintenance, us5341526, reinstatement

I am the owner of patent [US 5,341,526](http://www.google.com/patents/US5341526). Our mother was the original inventor and was going to pay the maintenance fees, but never did. So, we were told that we lost the patent.

Could you please tell me if there is any way to pay the fees to bring the status current again?

Comment: Hi Tracy, welcome to Ask Patents! We prefer to keep information here on the site, so I've gone ahead and edited your email out of your question. When you get an answer, it will show up below. Let me know if you have any questions or if I can clear anything up.

Comment: it has been partly answered in [expired due to failure to pay maintenance fees](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/12156/11895)

Answer (score 2):

Patents are territorial rights and for limited period of time(i.e. 20 years). subject query patent was filed in 1992 granted in 1994 and expired way back. Since your Mother assigned you patent in 1999 you could have paid fee till 2000. There is no point to revive the application which has passed its term.