# Is there any way to track Patents which are reinstated after non-payment of maintenance fees?

Tags: fees, maintenance, reinstatement, us7985418

I was tracking [US 7,985,418](http://www.google.com/patents/US7985418) claiming sevelamer compositions.

On 30th August on regular update in Pair I have seen status as "patent expired on 21.04.2014 due to nonpayment of maintenance fees".

Again on November 4th patent is still alive.

I don't have any screen shots to prove this case.

Will it be possible to track such issues with USPTO PAIR?

Answer (score 1):

If patent is lapsed due to non-payment of Maintenance fee one can revive it filing a Petition See Earlier answer [Failure to pay maintenance fees](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/12140/11895)

Now Such Petition is Hard to track As I see no option to find this information on PAIR. If a Petition is filed it is the matter between Patent office and applicant Ideally It should be made available via **Transaction History** of USPTO PAIR, but unfortunately its not.

Any ways the hard way is to weekly check for petition decided in said revival time frame.
One need to browse [USPTO Official Gazette](http://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/official-gazette/official-gazette-patents) **Notices** Section and further " Notice of Expiration of Patents Due to Failure to Pay Maintenance Fee" and " Patents Reinstated Due to the Acceptance of a Late Maintenance Fee from...."

[image]

Another quick way to do it using Google Advance search on USPTO OFFICIAL GAZETTE.

Comment: if its solved your query please accept the answer.